# Display XML file in html table

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

I have this XML file that I want to display in a html table using xslt:

```
<bottle>
         <composition>
            <ion type="positif">calcium 67.32mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="positif">magnésium 10.08mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">chlorure 20.82mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">nitrate 3.5mg/l</ion>
            <autre type="metal">fer</autre>
        </composition>
    </bottle>
     <bottle>
         <composition>
            <ion type="positif">calcium 60.32mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="positif">magnésium 15.28mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">chlorure 25.2mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">nitrate 1.5mg/l</ion>
        </composition>
</bottle>
```

I want to display every node like this:

```
----------------------------------
composition | positif            |
            |--------------------|
            | calcium 67.32mg/l  | 
            | magnésium 10.08mg/l| 
            |--------------------|
            | negatif            |
            |--------------------|
            | chlorure 20.82mg/l |
            | nitrate 3.5mg/l    | 
            |--------------------|
            | autre              |
            |--------------------|
            | fer                |
---------------------------------|
```

this is all I managed to do and it's not displaying anything:

```
<tr>
<th rowspan="6">Composition</th>                                    
<xsl:for-each select="document('Pub.xml')/Magasin/bouteille/composition[count(.| key('type-ion',@type)[1])=1]">

<th> <xsl:value-of select="@type"/> </th> 
<tr>
<td><xsl:for-each select="key('type-ion',@type)">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>                                     
</tr>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can i display that xml file in a table using xslt?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? This is a place to ask questions, not to get your code written for you.

Comment: **1.** Can you use XSLT 2.0? --- **2.** Please explain the logic in words. Why are ions grouped by type, but the others are not?

Comment: yes i am using XSLT 2.0 and both ions and others are grouped by type, here is my key: `<xsl:key name="type-ion" match="composition" use="@type" />`

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 2.0 is done by `xsl:for-each-group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an input of:

**XML**

```
<Magasin>
    <bouteille>
         <composition>
            <ion type="positif">calcium 67.32mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="positif">magnésium 10.08mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">chlorure 20.82mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">nitrate 3.5mg/l</ion>
            <autre type="metal">fer</autre>
        </composition>
    </bouteille>
     <bouteille>
         <composition>
            <ion type="positif">calcium 60.32mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="positif">magnésium 15.28mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">chlorure 25.2mg/l</ion>
            <ion type="negatif">nitrate 1.5mg/l</ion>
        </composition>
    </bouteille>
</Magasin>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="Magasin">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="composition">
    <xsl:variable name="height" select="count(distinct-values(*/@type)) + count (*)" />
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="@type">
            <tr>
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <th rowspan="{$height}">Composition</th>
                </xsl:if>
                <th>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </table>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="composition/*">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th rowspan="8">Composition</th>
            <th>positif</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>calcium 67.32mg/l</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>magnésium 10.08mg/l</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>negatif</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>chlorure 20.82mg/l</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>nitrate 3.5mg/l</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>metal</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>fer</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th rowspan="6">Composition</th>
            <th>positif</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>calcium 60.32mg/l</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>magnésium 15.28mg/l</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>negatif</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>chlorure 25.2mg/l</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>nitrate 1.5mg/l</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Rendered as:**

[image]

Comment: That was very generous of you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @michael.hor257k